# Updating a Button control with an NSTimer in Xamarin

Tags: ios, timer, xamarin, nstimer

I have created a very basic ios project that has a single button on it with it's title text property set to "Start".  I am trying to have this button count down from 15.

I have added the event handler for the button as below.

```
     void StartButton_TouchUpInside (object sender, EventArgs ea) {

        _currentCount = 15;

        _timer = NSTimer.CreateRepeatingScheduledTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>
            {

                if (_currentCount <= 0) {
                    StartButton.TitleLabel.Text = "Start";
                    _timer.Dispose();
                } else { 
                    string titleText = (_currentCount--).ToString ();
                    //Console.WriteLine(titleText);
                    StartButton.TitleLabel.Text = titleText;
                    //Console.WriteLine(StartButton.TitleLabel.Text);
                    //StartButton.SetNeedsDisplay();
                }
            });
    }
```

So here is the strange thing.  The Button changes to 15 just fine then it flashes back to "Start" then 14.  Then 13 then "Start" then 12 etc...  etc...  etc...

Why is it doing this? And how do I prevent it from flashing back to start.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try putting the count variable inside the timer delgate code

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this.InvokeOnMainThread

```
  private int counter = 0;
  public override void WillActivate()
  {        
     Console.WriteLine ("{0} will activate", this);
     _timer = NSTimer.CreateRepeatingScheduledTimer(1, (timer) =>
     {
        this.InvokeOnMainThread(()=>{
           Console.WriteLine("++++++++ NSTimer Call");
           this.AlertTimeLabel.SetText(counter.ToString());
           counter++;
        });
     });
  }
```